# Vuex State of an Array of Array is undefined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vuex

I have a store on Vuex with a socket listener. 
This listener add to the state messages an array of array.

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    messages: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SOCKET_GET_MESSAGES: (state, data) => {
      state.messages[data[0].recipient] = data[0].res
      // Data[0].recipient = the id of the recipient
      // Data[0].res is an object with a login and a message. 
    },
  }
```

In my console I can see the structure is correct if I do:

```
console.log(this.$store.state.messages)
```

with this output:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
2: Array(5)
 > 0: {login: "w", message: "ABCD", id: 65}
 > 1: {login: "w", message: "Deux", id: 66}
 > 2: {login: "w", message: "Quatre", id: 67}
 > 3: {login: "w", message: "J'envoie au deux", id: 69}
 > 4: {login: "w", message: "Test", id: 70}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 3
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(3), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

But if I ask a specific ID I get undefined in my console log. 
For example I ask for my first user with a message :

```
   console.log(this.$store.state.messages[2])
```

Do you know how to solve this issue ? 
I read lot of stuff on stackoverflow and on vuex documentation but I don't find an answer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you log `console.log(this.$store.state.message[1])` when it's already loaded?

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I add the console.log in the computed field and also in the component. I don't understand why nothing appears

Comment: Be sure to call the log when the data is actually loaded and check your store via the vue devtools in your browser console.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.$store.state.messages[1]` has to be defined because with the index 1 you are asking for the second element in your array. What happens if you log `this.$store.state.messages[0]` ?

Comment: You're using `data[0].recipient` as array "key". Are you sure you're trying to get the same index from this array? `state.messages[1521]` means the array has that many items, all but one are `undefined`. You need to query it with `this.$store.state.messages[1521]` in order to get it.

Comment: Provide an example (or screenshot) of `console.log(this.$store.state.messages)` and we'll see the problem ;)

Comment: Yes for example messages[0] don't exist because I don't have a user but messages[1] exist. I see the data available in the Vue devtools

Comment: @AndreyPopov you suspect little blue icon? probably

Comment: @AndreyPopov I just added in my question the output of console log. In this case I ask after the state.message[2]

Comment: @dfsq not sure what you're talking about :) @Brudger - just write both on the same console log and see what happens. We cannot know when you're trying to get those values. Either way it's much much better to use Object (or even some map if you're using newer JS) to store the values. `messages[10 000 000]` means array of that many items, for single user, while `object['user' + 10 000 000]` means object with single key...

Comment: @AndreyPopov I can't add on the same console log because I got undefined. But If I put just after the other console log I have undefined for the second one only. For objects on W3C they recommend to use array for numbers are you sure? How can I create an object with a number in my case? I'm not very familiar with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the array directly, without using any actual method to do so. Therefore Vue cannot pick up the change you've done. You need to either use `push` or some other Vue helpers like `$set`. Quoting some helper [docs](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating):

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).

Also, here's a [list](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods) of all supported mutation methods (wrapped by Vue):

```
push()
pop()
shift()
unshift()
splice()
sort()
reverse()
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. It's very interesting... Do you know how use the push function in this case ? `  state.messages.push({data[0].recipient: {message: data[0].res }})` seems create a syntax issue.

Comment: Here, push will queue the messages in ordered index. You cannot specify the index. It will be `state.messages.push({ message: data[0].res})` and you'll lose your functionality of mapping. If you need that functionality - use `$set` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, 
After some research I want complete the answer of Andrey Popov. 
Indeed if we use Vuex we need to use directly:

```
  Vue.set(state.object, key, data)
```

The this.$set method is not available in Vuex. 
It's now working with this method.